# Experience Editor not working properly in 8.2

Tags: experience-editor, installation

We upgraded to 8.2 back in August and haven't had issues on the front or the back end for the most part.  However we don't use the Experience Editor very much.  Our client might but hasn't reported issues.  However, when I access the Experience Editor on any of our platforms, I have issues such as the close button not working, and also errors on some of our pages `buttonRoot isn't set for edit frame`.

When I look at browser tools, it's reporting a whole bunch of Experience Editor files missing.  All of these seem to be in the `/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Request` folder or sub-folders beneath that, however when I look at all our various platforms, I see up to the `/Speak` folder, but there is no Request folder beneath that.

Apparently we did an out of the box install of 8.2, so I'm confused as to why these would be missing and how we might get copies so that we can get the Experience Editor working properly again.

Comment: "buttonRoot isn't set for edit frame" used to be a know problem when you switched on Sitecore Desktop to "core" database and then still tried to do things in Experience Editor.

Comment: Levi is this the case on all environments? if so I'd suggest identifying the missing files, getting a copy of each of them from the original install zip folder and placing them in the correct locations manually. Then ensure these changes are tracked in source control and deployed out to your environments.

Comment: Just downloaded the initial release and it is missing the Request folder as well.  I also went through and made sure there weren't any markup issues on the page, it's now validating perfectly but still giving the errors.  The ribbon comes up, but I cannot close it via the close icon/button.  Been looking for solutions but so far haven't found anything...